# ASP.NET MVC 2 Areas 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Has anyone been able to get the Areas in ASP.NET MVC 2 to work?

I created a new Area called "Secure" and placed a new controller in it named HomeController. I then Created a new Home/Index.aspx view. However, when I browse to http://localhost/myapp/Secure/ it gives a 404 resource cannot be found. http://localhost/myapp/Secure/Home gives the same error.

My area registration looks like this:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Secure_default",
                "Secure/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

I also tried this:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Secure_default",
                "Secure/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, i've got Areas working with ASP.NET MVC 2.

Its hard for people to debug routes over SO, the easiest way is for you to use [Phil Haacks Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx). It'll tell you what routes (and areas) are being resolved for a particular URL. Extremely handy.

However ill take a stab, try changing your route to this:

```
       context.MapRoute(
            "Secure_default",
            "Secure",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The url (`<yourhost>/Secure`) will find your area `Secure` but not know which controller you hand the request to, as you have not specified a default value for `controller` in your areas route.

Here's my setup:

```
Areas
      Albums
           Controllers
                AlbumsController.cs (namespace Web.Areas.Albums.Controllers)
           Models
           Views
                Albums
                     Index.aspxx
           AlbumsAreaRegistration.cs
                context.MapRoute(
                    "Albums_Default",
                    "Albums",
                    new { controller = "Albums", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional)
```

The URL: http://localhost/Albums triggers the "Index" action of my "AlbumsController" in my "Albums" area.

What does you structure look like?

Comment: Changing the MapRoute to that didn't have any effect. I added his route debugger DLL and when I go to /secure it says it matches even though without the debugger DLL I get a 404:

Matched Route: Secure/{controller}/{action}/{id}
True Secure/{controller}/{action}/{id} controller = Home, action = Index, id = System.Web.Mvc.UrlParameter (null) Namespaces = System.String[], area = Secure, UseNamespaceFallback = False

Comment: Could namespaces be an issue? My SecureAreaRegistration class is in namespace TothSolutions.Web.Areas.Secure and my HomeController class is in namespace TothSolutions.Web.Areas.Secure.Controllers.

Comment: No - that namespace is correct. I'll update my answer with my structure for my Area.

Comment: Mine looks the same except Secure instead of Albums. :( The worst part is that the route tester says "True" for "Matches Current Request" for the Url "Secure" when I browse to http://localhost/TothSolutions/secure, very sad...

Comment: Also I should point out that I've tried using the Visual Studio server instead of IIS - http://localhost:99/Secure - and that gives the same 404...

Comment: Interestingly, with the same exact code it works for another developer so it has to be configuration related. I've tried the Visual Studio server, an IIS subdirectory, and the IIS root and all give the 404, anything else I should try?

Comment: Hmm....thats interesting. So both you and the other developer have the same code, both use VS Server, theirs works and yours dont? Thats bizarre. Maybe temp files hanging around? (try a clean solution).

Sorry mate - ive run out of ideas. =)

Comment: Yeah I tried clean solution, didn't work. Thanks for the help, I'm at a loss as well... I'm going to try it on my 2nd computer and see if that works.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure it was because your area registration class was in a different namespace that the project it was hosted in.  It would explain why your solution worked - you registered it with the overload that takes in the namespace.  I had a similar issue and it was fixed by correcting the namespace.

Comment: Namespaces were wrong for me. I was missing the ".Areas." part

Answer (score 2):

I got it working, the answer was to change the area registration class to this:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Secure_Default", // Route name
                "Secure/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { area="Secure", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                new[] { typeof(Controllers.HomeController).Namespace }
            );
```

I have no idea why it worked for another developer and not for me, also I feel like it should "just work" out of the box when you create a new Area, you shouldn't have to fiddle with the route mapping.

Anyway, thanks all for the help and I'm giving the answer to RPM for all his hard work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() in your global.asax?

```
Sub Application_Start()
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's put there by default when creating a new MVC2 Web Application. Unless he has manually removed it by mistake of course.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using http://localhost/myapp/Secure/Home/index ? I find so many times that when I use index as the view name and don't specify it in the path it never works. It should work but it never works for me.

I don't like calling my views index anyways so not a big deal for me.